# Ubuntu - Standalone Magnify Tool

Tags: ubuntu, web-development

Is there a standalone magnify tool for Ubuntu to zoom in on applications (for web development more than anything)?

I'm aware of [XMag](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xmag.1.html), but wondered whether there was something better than that available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zoom the whole screen, you can use <kbd>Super</kbd> + the mouse wheel. On most keyboards, the super key will be the Windows key. You need desktop effects enabled to use this feature.

If you just want to zoom on a selection, there is [**Virtual Magnifying Glass**](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/#download), a free, open source, screen magnifier, for Windows, Linux, FreeBSD and Mac OS X:

[image]

Comment: I can't use the first option under Ubuntu (no compiz).  Virtual Magnifier Glass Didn't work for me under Ubuntu 9.10, threw some horrible exceptions on startup.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu 16.04**

---

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

The terminal opens, type

```
apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Go to Ubuntu icon on Top Left corner of desktop

[image]

Click on it and type compiz

[image]

Click on the compiz icon that appers in the window

The following window opens:

[image]

Click on OK

Go to Accebility --> Enhanced Zoom Desktop --> Tick the box

[image]

Click on Enhanced Zoom Desktop

[image]

Click on Zoom In Key --> Disabled

[image]

Tick the box Enabled

[image]

Click on Grab Key Combination

[image]

Press together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

[image]

Click on OK

[image]

Click on Zoom Out Key --> Disabled

[image]

Tick on the box Enabled

[image]

Click on Grab Key Combination

[image]

Press  together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image]

Click on OK

[image]

Close the window

[image]

From now on

to Zoom In press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

and to Zoom Out press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>